# Client can't do nslookup to my bind9 server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, bind

I'm trying to make a DNS server using bind9, however when i try to use nslookup or i try to resolve the name, it gives me a servfail error.

Here is the configuration files:

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the 
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize 
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
smx@smx:~$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local 
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "thiefhunter.local"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.thiefhunter.local";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168.1";
};
```

Here is my reverse zone configuration:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.thiefhunter.local root.thiefhunter.local. (
                 2      ; Serial
            604800      ; Refresh
             86400      ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
            604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
    IN  NS  ns1.thiefhunter.local.
ns1 IN  A   192.168.1.37
server  IN  CNAME   ns1.thiefhunter.local.
pc01    IN  A   192.168.1.36
gw  IN  A   192.168.1.1
```

A thing i want to remark: i don't know what means the pc01 IN A 192.168.1.36, there's no PC with this ip in my network, however i followed the tutorial and that thing appeared, i'm sorry in advice.

Here is my reverse zone configuration:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.thiefhunter.local root.thiefhunter.local. (
                 1      ; Serial
            604800      ; Refresh
             86400      ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
            604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.thiefhunter.local.
10  IN  PTR ns1.thiefhunter.local.
1   IN  PTR gw.thiefhunter.local.
```

I didn't edited the /etc/bind/named.conf because i didn't think its needed,

Also, here are the error when i try to use nslookup with the client (who have configure to use my bind9 server IP as DNS):

```
paco@paco-virtualbox:~$ nslookup
> thiefhunter.local
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find thiefhunter.local: SERVFAIL
> 192.168.1.37
** server can't find 37.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
> 192.168.1
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find 192.168.1: NXDOMAIN
```

Thanks for your time and thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Ot looks like you are a bit confused and/or are looking at a bad tutorial.

The first zone file is not usef for reverse DNS - it is a forward lookup ehich converts domains ending in thiefhunter.local" to IP addresses. You will want to add a record

```
  server      192.168.1.37
```

It is the second zone file tjat does reverse lookups.  You need to add the appropriate entry in it to convert an IP to a domain.

The left side of this is the last digit of the IP address - in your case 37.  The right side is the domain name to resolve - eg mymachine.thiefhunter.local.

```
  37      server.thiefhunter.local.
```

"pc01 IN A 192.168.1.36" is an entry which will convert pc01.thiefhunter.local to an IP address 192.168.1.36 - and can likrlt be deleted if therr is no machine on that IP.